# python pdf text position on output

Tags: python, pdf

Looking for some advice on the best way to achieve an accurate PDF output.

Basically, I have a CSV that I need to extract the values from and output them to a PDF file. However, I have a PDF template that I need to 'fill in' with the values so I'm looking for a way to grab the PDF template and then accurately position some text on it and then output a new PDF will all of the values filled in.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can use [PyPDF](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.24) or the fdfgen module.

Comment: Thanks Alfrenardi. I've gone with reportlab which seems to have the functionality I'm after.